# ssl.SSLWantReadError: The operation did not complete (read) (_ssl.c:2536)

Tags: python-3.10

```
import httpx
import asyncio


baseUrl = "https://ec.europa.eu/tools/eudamed/api/devices/udiDiData"
params = {
    "page": "0",
    "pageSize": "25",
    "size": "25",
    "sort": ["primaryDi,ASC", "versionNumber,DESC"],
    "iso2Code": "en",
    "cndCode": "A01",
    "deviceStatusCode": "refdata.device-model-status.on-the-market",
    "languageIso2Code": "en",
}

# r = httpx.get(baseUrl, params=params)


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        r = await client.get(baseUrl, params=params)
        print(r.text)


asyncio.run(main())
```

error i am running into

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\anyio\streams\tls.py", line 108, in _call_sslobject_method
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 916, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len)
ssl.SSLWantReadError: The operation did not complete (read) (_ssl.c:2536)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue and was able to fix it using a timeout. As per [httpx docs](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#timeout-configuration), the default timeout is 5 seconds so I increased it to 15 (adjust it as per your needs). The updated code would be :

```
async def main():
    timeout_in_seconds = 15.0
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=timeout_in_seconds) as client:
        r = await client.get(baseUrl, params=params)
```

If you want more flexibility, you can add the timeout at the request level as well:

```
timeout_in_seconds = httpx.Timeout(15.0)
r = await client.get(baseUrl, params=params, timeout=timeout_in_seconds )
```

Answer (score -4):

Try disabling SSL verification:

```py
async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(verify=False) as client:
        r = await client.get(baseUrl, params=params)
        print(r.text)
```